# This algorithm takes more time than expected

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming

I have this code, where i would call this "checkingfunction"  function. I am not using any threading in my app, I would love to use if it benefits the performance of my app.

The "checkingfunction", takes more time than i expected. It takes more than 30 seconds to complete the execution. I cant wait that long in my app. That is not good, in middle of the game.

Somebody help me out here to rewrite the function, so that i can execute it in a faster way. Some functional programming way, if possible.

```
func returnCharactersFromAFourLetterString(inputString : String) -> (First : Character,Second : Character, Third : Character, Fourth : Character)
{
    return (inputString[advance(inputString.startIndex, 0)],inputString[advance(inputString.startIndex, 1)],inputString[advance(inputString.startIndex, 2)],inputString[advance(inputString.startIndex, 3)])
}

func checkingWords(userEnteredWord : String)
{

    var tupleFourLetters = self.returnCharactersFromAFourLetterString(userEnteredWord)

    var firstLetter = String(tupleFourLetters.First)
    var secondLetter = String(tupleFourLetters.Second)
    var thirdLetter = String(tupleFourLetters.Third)
    var fourthLetter = String(tupleFourLetters.Fourth)

    var mainArrayOfWords : [String] = [] // This array contains around 0.2 million words
    var userEnteredTheseWords : [String] = []  // This array contains less than 10 elements

    // Check for FirstLetter

    for index in 0..<array.count // Array of Letters as Strings , count = 200
    {
        var input  = array[index]
        var firstWord = "\(input)\(secondLetter)\(thirdLetter)\(fourthLetter)"
        var secondWord = "\(firstLetter)\(input)\(thirdLetter)\(fourthLetter)"
        var thirdWord = "\(firstLetter)\(secondLetter)\(input)\(fourthLetter)"
        var fourthWord = "\(firstLetter)\(secondLetter)\(thirdLetter)\(input)"

        if !contains(userEnteredTheseWords, firstWord) && !contains(userEnteredTheseWords, secondWord) && !contains(userEnteredTheseWords, thirdWord) && !contains(userEnteredTheseWords, fourthWord)
        {
            if contains(mainArrayOfWords, firstWord )
            {
                self.delegate?.wordMatchedFromDictionary(firstWord)
                return
            }
            else if contains(mainArrayOfWords, secondWord)
            {
                self.delegate?.wordMatchedFromDictionary(secondWord)
                return
            }
            else if contains(mainArrayOfWords, thirdWord)
            {
                self.delegate?.wordMatchedFromDictionary(thirdWord)
                return
            }
            else if contains(mainArrayOfWords, fourthWord)
            {
                self.delegate?.wordMatchedFromDictionary(fourthWord)
                return
            }
        }

        if index == array.count - 1
        {
            self.delegate?.wordMatchedFromDictionary("NoWord")
        }
    }
}
```

Input of this function is a four letter word, Inside this function i am changing each letter by looping through that 200 letters, and checking in the mainArray that, whether any of these changed words exists in mainArray. If exists, then return me that word, otherwise just return NoWord. So totally, we can see that we are checking that contains(mainArray, word) thing around 800 times, i think this is the line which consumes more time, cause mainArray contains 0.2 million words.

Comment: So what have you done to try to make it faster? Where in the method is it slow?

Comment: It isn't clear what **your actual problem** is - please explain the purpose of this code, its input and what the required output is.  It looks like it is searching a list of words for matches?

Comment: First thing I would try is to change `mainArrayOfWords` to a constant (eg `let` instead of `var`). And also try changing it from an array to a dictionary. Check if that doesn't boost your performance a bit. Generally you can change many of your vars to lets.

Comment: @Paulw11 Question modified.

Comment: @StephenDarlington I think contains(mainArray, word) , this causes the main problem. We have to check this around 800 times, Means looping through 0.2 million words 800 times. Is there any way to modify this code.?

Comment: @Mellson Changing to let , may not solve it.

Comment: @AlvinVarghese no that will not do it alone, but generally using let can make it easier for the compiler to optimize the code. Try changing to a dictionary first and see how far that gets you.

Comment: @Mellson Let me do it.

Comment: CoreData with indexed word might help.

Comment: I don't understand the `Inside this function i am changing each letter by looping through that 200 letters` part of your question. 200 letters?

Comment: @EricD. ["A","B","C"] , Some other language letters also.

Comment: @AlvinVarghese You mean you're using more than one alphabet, which makes it 200 letters?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to see if your word list, `mainArrayOfWords`, contains a word that differs from the input by one character? (Your description still doesn't say what the code is supposed to accomplish, only how it attempts to do it.)

Comment: @molbdnilo Absolutley

Answer (score 2):

Use dictionaries to look up things.

When you measure times, especially with Swift code, measure a release build, not a debug build. On the other hand, measure on the slowest device capable of running your code.